# API Call In React return empty array

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, api

```
const item = '10';
var url ='https://localhost:44346/API/Bills?pServiceID='+item;
try { 
   useEffect(() => {
   fetch(url, { headers }) 
      .then( (res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
       for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
       {
         var useraccount = data[i];
         database.push(useraccount);
        }
  })
}, []);
} catch (error) {
  this.setState({ error });
}
```

When executing this API call in react and debugging it the debugger never goes into .then code, I have tested the URL from Fiddler and it works fine
Also in the code above fetch does fetch any errors

Please note I'm testing using localhost
Regards

Comment: A couple of things to try. Remove the try catch from the outside and put it inside the useEffect. Put a console.log in the first ".then" call and check if has a value there?